# IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL during run of Adobe CS 4 product

Tags: bsod

I get bluesreen `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` during running of Photoshop CS 4 or Ilustrator CS 4 on Windows XP Home edition SP3.

Details of error:
`IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL 0x0000000A (0x911A7008 0x00000002 0x00000001 0x8052390D)`

What can be cause?

Comment: By during running, do you mean "when I start it", "after a few minutes", or "after an hour or something, in middle of work"?

Comment: In the middle of work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two main causes is usually either faulty memory (1) or bad drivers(2).

(1) I recommend you run [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org), which should show if you have any bad memory in your system.

(2) If you have a lot of badly coded drivers installed on your system - especially if you buy a lot of USB tat, it is possible that the drivers corrupt other items on your system. Uninstall things that you no longer need, but it is always hard to advise on this without seeing the actual system. I still advise you do (1) first.

Lastly, Try running [Bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), and see if it shows you the name of the faulting module (usually the third or so line up from the bottom of the BSOD screen). The thing is, whilst IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL shows a problem, just saying that does not easily tell us what the problem is with.

Comment: Okay, I'll be running memtest tonight

Comment: It was damaged ram - I forgot to come and accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly caused by overheating hardware or faulty RAM.
To isolate software issue, you could try to boot from live cd /disks. If it boots fine, then it could be the OS/applications issue with the hard disk. 
If this problem is faced after addition of new device which has really bad IRQ, remove the new device and see if the problem is resolved.
Or run Memtest as suggested by Will to ensure that memory is not faulty.